# C# won't execute a command

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string nume;
        int A = 0;
        int B = 0;
        int C = 0;
        char comanda;

        Console.WriteLine ("Va rugam sa va introduceti numele:");

        nume = Convert.ToString (Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine ("\n Buna ziua, " + nume + ", ce doriti sa comandati?");
        Console.WriteLine ("\n Castraveti(A)");
        Console.WriteLine ("\n Ceai(B)");
        Console.WriteLine ("\n Gogosi!(C)");

        comanda = Convert.ToChar (Console.ReadKey()); // Here is the problem, when I enter A, B or C the console will just shut down.

        if(comanda == A) {
            int raspuns;
            int D = 0;
            int E = 0;
            Console.WriteLine ("Murati(D) sau proaspeti(E)?");
            raspuns = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            if (raspuns == D) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Poftiti castravetii murati");
            }
            if (raspuns == E){
                Console.WriteLine ("Poftiti castravetii proaspeti");
            }

        } else if(comanda == B){
            Console.WriteLine ("Multumim pentru comanda, aici este ceaiul");
        } else if(comanda == C) {

            int X = 0;
            int Y = 0;
            int raspuns;

            Console.WriteLine ("Aa! Buna alegere, nu crezi?\n Da(X), nu(Y)");
            raspuns = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            if (raspuns == X){
                Console.WriteLine ("Si eu!! Poti lua gogoasa, nici nu mai trebuie sa platesti :D");
            }
            if (raspuns == Y){
                Console.WriteLine (".....mda, nu te inteleg. Nu o sa mai primesti gogoasa!");
            }

            Console.ReadKey ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get on that line is "Unable to cast object of type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Comment: See the documentation for `Console.ReadKey`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Key` Property:

```
char myChar = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().Key);
```

or

```
char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

**Edit:**

As @juharr pointed out:

`Console.ReadKey().Key` always returns the upper case letter and for numbers always the numeric value, even if shift is pressed.

Comment: Or better yet just `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`.

Comment: `Console.ReadKey().Key` does not differentiate between upper and lower case characters.

Comment: If you use `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().Key)` and type in a lower case r you'll get an upper case R.  Worse if you type in Shift-3 for # you get 3 instead of #.  `ConsoleKey` is an enum that tells you which non-modifier key was pressed, not what character was typed.

Comment: Ah, you're right, just made a copy&paste error when testing